# OPEN SRS With Drupal

Tags: 7

I am new to Drupal 7 . I need to integrate opensrs (third party api for domain reselling) with Drupal 7 . 
OPensrs provided API (`[`http://www.opensrs.com/`][1]`)
I don't know how to use PHP APi provide by opensrs. Anybody tell me how to do this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?  If you are having trouble with the PHP API itself, you should ask OpenSRS support, not here-- this site is strictly for Drupal-related issues.  If you're having trouble integrating the API with Drupal, please describe in more detail what kind of issues you are facing.